# paypal REST endpoint

Tags: rest, paypal

Iv been working to intergrate the paypal REST API  into  a web application, its now time to change from the sandbox endpoint to the live endpoint, but iv hit a snag, it seems like the live endpoints have dropped from the  face of the earth. the sandbox environement works, `api.sandbox.paypal.com`   and i can reach it via ping and so on, 
but not `api.paypal.com` which is  the live endpoint according to `developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications` i can not even ping the live server, both from my local development environment and a cloud server instance. im i doing something wrong?

Edit: 
solved, see comment

Comment: The status site shows they did have some issues with REST:  https://www.paypal-notify.com/eventnotification/search?eventSearchType=PayPalSiteStatus  It says it's been resolved, however, I'm currently unable to ping it right now.

Comment: @AndrewAngell  do the live endpoints support  ICMP ping?  i cant reach even the classic endpoints like api-3t.paypal.com

Comment: I guess not.  I'm not able to ping that either, but all my calls are working just fine.  I really haven't done anything with REST yet so I don't have any quick tests setup for that.

Comment: Are you getting a specific error when trying to run a payment on Live?

Comment: sorry, i found that it is working now, not sure what was going on, but it responds fine, the code worked in  the sandbox, stopped working on change over to live, then i backtracked, found it was also broken in sandbox, fixed it and its ok now.  maybe the problem was between the seat and keyboard :)